# Python XGBoost prediction discrepancies with DMatrix

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost

I found there are 2 problems with `xbgoost` predictions. I trained the model with `XGBClassifier` and tried to load the model using `Booster` for prediction, I found

1. Predictions are slightly different using `xbg.Booster` and `xgb.Classifier`, see below.

[image]

2. Predictions are different between `list` and `numpy array` when using `DMatrix`, see below,

[image]

Some difference is quite big, I am not sure why this is happening and which prediction should be the source of truth?

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, your data types could change when you convert a list to a numpy array (depending on the numpy version you're using). For example on numpy 1.19.5, try converting list ["1",1] to a numpy array and see the result.